# How can I use literal single quotes inside the argument to perl's -e?

Tags: perl, special-characters

I try to create a short `perl` command that creates SQL inserts for my DB based on a text file. However, I am not able to get in the single-quotes used by SQL

```
perl -pe '$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; $_ = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES($i, \'$a[4]\');\n"'
```

results in a syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Any ideas?

Comment: This is one of the reasons you have q and qq in Perl. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -pe '$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; $_ = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES($i, \047$a[4]\047);\n";'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape them for the shell, not for Perl.  This requires a slightly different syntax.  Assuming you're running this under bash, ksh, or similar, then

```
perl -e 'print "greengrocer'\''s\n"'
```

should print `greengrocer's`.

Alternatively, you could insert the character as a hex escape sequence:

```
perl -e 'print "greengrocer\x27s\n"'
```

Answer (score 1):

`perl -pe "\$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; \$_ = \"INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES(\$i, '\$a[4]');\n\""`

From [this page](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-quoting.html) it states for BASH: "A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.". So use double quotes instead and escape as necessary.

Comment: double quotes do not fit the needs. because there are double quotes in the inserted strings.

Comment: Did you even try running this? You will find that the double quotes come out as you expect.

Comment: If you're going to quote your string with double-quotes, it's easier to use Perl's qq() syntax for double-quoted strings:  qq( ... ) is equivalent to " ... "

Answer (score 1):

Use the technique @Porculus suggested in his answer:

```
perl -pe '$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; $_ = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES($i, '\''$a[4]'\'');\n";'
```

This closes the single-quoted string just before the single quote, then uses an escaped single-quote, then opens a new single-quoted string.

The beauty of this technique is that you can automate it:

```
sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/" <<'EOF'
$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; $_ = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES($i, '$a[4]');\n";
EOF
```

resulting a properly-quoted string you can paste on to the command line :

```
'$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; $_ = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES($i, '\''$a[4]'\'');\n";'
```

Or you can make a shell-script for it:

```
$ cat > quotify
#!/bin/sh
sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e "s/^/'/" -e "s/$/'/"
^D
$ chmod +x quotify
$ ./quotify
$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; $_ = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES($i, '$a[4]');\n";
^D
'$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; $_ = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES($i, '\''$a[4]'\'');\n";'
```

(The above sed firstly replaces each `'` with `'\''` then puts a `'` at the front and back.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work-around by using a | for all single-quote and then in a second perl call replacing this | by a single quote (`perl -pe "s/\|/'/g"`)

```
perl -pe '$i += 1; chomp; @a = split /\t/; $_ = "INSERT INTO XYZ VALUES($i, |$a[4]|, |$a[5]|, |$a[7]|, |$a[0]|, |$a[1]|, |$a[3]|);\n"' | perl -pe "s/\|/'/g"
```

Still interested in a better solution.